# Assigning group ID by incrementing sample number

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have data from a logger that identifies samples with consecutive numbers per group, but the raw data doesn't include a group identifier. One can tell where a new group starts because the sample ID == 1.

How can I assign a grouping variable so that I can use `group_by()` to do group-wise summaries, etc.?

```r
df_have <- tribble(
  ~n, ~value,
  1, .1,
  2, .3,
  1, .2,
  2, .4,
  3, .6,
  1, .7
)

df_want <- tribble(
  ~group, ~n, ~value,
  "A", 1, .1,
  "A", 2, .3,
  "B", 1, .2,
  "B", 2, .4,
  "B", 3, .6,
  "C", 1, .7
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the current row with the previous row and increment the counter using `cumsum` if the difference is less than 1. We can use inbuilt-vector `LETTERS` to assign group name.

```
library(dplyr)

df_have %>%
  mutate(group = LETTERS[cumsum(n - lag(n, default = first(n)) < 1)])

#     n value group
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1     1   0.1 A    
#2     2   0.3 A    
#3     1   0.2 B    
#4     2   0.4 B    
#5     3   0.6 B    
#6     1   0.7 C
```

The same logic in base R can be implemented as :

```
transform(df_have, group = LETTERS[cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(n) < 1))])
```

Comment: Thanks! And I guess if I have more than 26 groups, I'd just remove the LETTERS[...] bit to have the group remain a number.